# Keywait fails when used with same key but different functions?

Tags: autohotkey

Here's the thing that im trying to achieve - i want `xbutton1` to do nothing when held for more than half sec and if its less than half execute `browser_back`. i want the `volume_up` to perform irrespective of the `keywait` condition. but keywait doesn't work?

---

My code:

```
XButton1 & WheelUp:: Volume_Up

XButton1::
KeyWait ,XButton1,T0.5  
if (errorlevel = 0)  
send {Browser_Back}  

return
```

Comment: I'm not able to notice anything wrong with the functionality on my end. What is supposed to go wrong?

Comment: @0x464e It performs Browser_back even after holding xbutton1 for more than 0.5sec! which shouldn't be happening right?

Comment: It's not happening on my end. It works as expected on my end. Is this your full script or is there something else in your script as well? And just in case, maybe try updating your AHK if you're on some old version (you update by just redownloading and running the official installer)